# How do I stop a Flash CS4 Motion Tween?

Tags: flash, cs4, tween, motion

I've started using Motion Tweening in CS4 and I am puzzled by something with how the durations are set. The best way I can describe this is by comparing it to what are now called Classic Tweens…

In a Classic Tween, I set the beginning and end keyframes of a particular animation, and when the playhead reaches the ending keyframe, the animation stops…

In a CS4+ Motion Tween, I set the first keyframe and then make changes using the motion editor, but when I add frames to the timeline, the tween keeps on growing, and the animation doesn't stop correctly. Is there some trick to telling the Motion Tween that it should only be X amount of frames?

Answer (score 0):

Select the frame where you want your object to stop moving. Select the object in that layer drag it to where you want it to go. Once you release the object it will now stop on the frame you had selected.